# Replace with sed content between a word and last word before a dot

Tags: regex, sed

I can have this type of html

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/javascripts/docs/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../common.css" type="text/css" />
```

I want to replace the path between `src="` or `href="` and `X.js` or `X.css`. I have a working version on https://regex101.com/r/45ekfL/3 but why it is not working with sed?

Result I want:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../doc/new/test/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../doc/new/test/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../doc/new/test/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../doc/new/test/style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../doc/new/test/common.css" type="text/css" />
```

The closest I have for javascript link is:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/app.js"></script>' | \
    sed -E 's#(src=").*(\w*.js)#\1/new/path/\2#'
```

with a `#` flag because I inject slash for my new path.

It gives me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/new/path/.js"></script>
```

If I add the missing slash before the last capture group `(src=").*\/(\w*.js)` my sed is not working anymore.

Why?
Can I use named capture group? Is is a good idea?

I am on osx but the command will be used on ubuntu machines too.

Comment: The problem is that `.*` is greedy, so it matches as much as it can and then `\w*` doesn't match anything.

Comment: Sed doesn't support named capture groups, it only supports BRE and ERE.

Comment: It seems to work fine with `(src=").*\/(\w*.js)`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/nk0P5N). Note you need to escape the dot before `js`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It does not work on osx. My sed deal with the regex probably differently. :/

Comment: I don't know osx but as `\w` is non standard, have you checked that your sed supports it ? Anyway `\w*` does not match well filenames, it will fail for example with `app.min.js` or `app-v2.js`. You can try this instead : `s#(src=")[^"]*(/[^"]*\.js")#\1/new/path\2#`. Also please note that using a regex to parse html is usually considered a bad practice because this language is potentially too complex, so you should do that only with simple pieces of html with a known structure.

Comment: Thanks. It is working with `'s#(src=").*\/([a-z]*.js)#\1/new/path/\2#'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment

> I don't know osx but as \w is non standard

So here is two proposal

```
sed -E 's#(src=")[^"]*(/[^"]*\.js")#\1/new/path\2#'
```

or

```
sed -E 's#(src=").*\/([a-z]*.js)#\1/new/path/\2#'
```

But keep mine processing html is not recommended:

> using a regex to parse html is usually considered a bad practice because this language is potentially too complex